# Is it possible to work around the cross domain iframe limitation?

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

I'm using a third party app which in its current beta status unfortunately lacks customizations options for the iframe integration of that service.

Since the iframe is coming from their website, I can't manipulate it using jQuery.
I understand the reason for all these security measures, but I still need to ask: is it possible to work around this limitation?

I have read about faking the iframe src and redirecting it to your own webserver, essentially creating a new iframe with the same content. Are such things possible or is it impossible what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible, although depending on what you're doing it could be considered bad form, or a nasty hack. Here's a lib for NodeJS that will help with doing it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inject